# DataGridView displays the Time as a date

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, time, datagridview, datatable

I have a CSV file which has a column for time and the time is formatted to look like (in the CSV file)
    08:22:07

DataGridView will convert it to look like

```
12/30/1899 8:22 AM
```

Any suggestions?

My code looks like

```
    public static DataTable ParseCSV(string path, String pattern)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
            return null;
        string full = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        string file = Path.GetFileName(full);
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(full);
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
            + "Data Source=\"" + dir + "\\\";"
            + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"";
        string query = "SELECT [Pc-Tag], [User-Name], [Date], [Time] FROM " + file;// +" WHERE [User-Name] LIKE " + pattern;
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
        try
        {
            dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ioe.Message.ToString());
        }
        dAdapter.Dispose();
        return dTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure the column to use a certain format string like `T`, which is the long time format (hh:mm:ss).

Use the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property of the column containing your time value to do that. You can either use the Forms designer (click the little arrow that's displayed when you select the `DataGridView` control and then choose "Edit columns", select the column and then press the "..." button for the `DefaultCellStyle` property) or you can do it in code.

Just make sure to add the columns manually (either in the designer or in code) and set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows do you expect?
For few (<1000) rows I would do:

```
....
dAdapter.Dispose();

dtable.Columns.Add("Custom", typeof(string));

foreach(var row in dtable.Rows)
{
     row["Custom"] = "17:15:30"; //here goes your logic to convert the Time Value
                                 // example: row["Time"].ToString("T");
}

return dTable;
```

Another solution with better performance is to add an expression column;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
var expression = "SUBSTRING([Time], 11, IF(LEN([Time]) = 19, 8, 7))";
dtable.Columns.Add("Custom", typeof(string), expression);
```

Comment: What would you do if you had 1500 rows?

Comment: @Thorsten - I would use an expression, which is way faster. Look at my updated solution.